# Emacs, use Delete key to delete selection

Tags: emacs, textselection

First of all, this is not a dup of

- [how to delete region with [delete] key in emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924205/how-to-delete-region-with-delete-key-in-emacs), which is for Emacs 23, and the answer is Emacs `cua-mode`.
- [How configure delete-selection-mode to only delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036325/how-configure-delete-selection-mode-to-only-delete), which is for Emacs 22, and the issue is not reproducable.

I'm talking about the [Emacs Delete Selection Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeleteSelectionMode), I used to be able to delete selection of text by just pressing <kbd>Delete</kbd> key. I found my proof [here](http://notfaq.wordpress.com/2006/07/20/delete-selected-text/).

> In order to set emacs to delete the selected text when you press DEL, Ctrl-d, or Backspace, add the following to your .emacs file:

```
(delete-selection-mode t)
```

However, now, with my Emacs 24, the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key doesn't work on the selection anymore (only <kbd>Backspace</kbd> does). This is really annoying because for all editors that I use, pressing the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key will delete the text selection. I don't understand why Emacs has to be so different and inconvenient. Anyway,

Any easy way to fix it? I don't know whether [the comment](http://notfaq.wordpress.com/2006/07/20/delete-selected-text/) of the following was a joke or the actual solution:

```
(setq behave-like-something-actually-usable-by-humans t)
```

Thanks

PS, my Emacs 24 is from nightly build:

```
$ emacs --version | head -1 
GNU Emacs 24.3.50.1
```

**EDIT:** The answer from Drew, if it is unclear to you (I got that on third attempt),

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<delete>") '(lambda (n) (interactive "p") (if (use-region-p) (delete-region (region-beginning) (region-end)) (delete-char n))))
```

works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<delete>` key is bound by default to `kill-line`.  It sounds like you want to bind it instead to `delete-region`.  Just do it.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<delete>") 'delete-region)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Oh... Hold on... If I do that, and if there is no text selection exist, the behavior is surprising! Lots of lots of things get deleted. I think it's everything from the cursor to the hidden spot that last text selection exist.

Comment: That's because the region is defined, even when it is not active.  So bind it to a command that does nothing unless the region is active (or that does something else in that case). E.g. bind it to `(lambda () (interactive) (when (use-region-p) (delete-region (region-beginning) (region-end))))` or `(lambda (n) (interactive "p") (if (use-region-p) (delete-region (region-beginning) (region-end)) (delete-char n)))`

Answer (score 0):

There appears to have been a change to the behavior of `delete-char`. I experienced that as well as I had bound DEL to that command. I had success binding the key to `delete-forward-char` instead, which implements the old behavior. See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Erasing.html#Erasing).

Answer (score 0):

In 21.4.22, I had to use the `(region-active-p)` function instead of `(use-region-p)`

```
(global-set-key `backspace '(lambda (n) (interactive "p") (if (region-active-p) (delete-region (region-beginning) (region-end)) (delete-backward-char n))))
```