# Let .emacs.d behaves just like a .d folder

Tags: emacs, configuration, configuration-files

I want to solve my “[.emacs bankruptcy](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DotEmacsBankruptcy)” issue, and I've gone through

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EmacsHowto
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DotEmacsBankruptcy
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DotEmacsDotD
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html

and it is still unclear to me whether the `.emacs.d` folder is the solution. I.e., whether it will behave just like a normal .d folder, e.g., `/etc/profile.d/`, where you drop you scripts and they will be picked up by the system auto-magically. Please confirm.

If not, can someone give me a script that does that, or give me a solution please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The essential content of my `~/.emacs` file is:

```lisp
(require 'cl)

(loop for src in (directory-files "~/.emacs.d" 'full-path "[0-9].*\\.el$") do
      (let ((byte (concat src "c")))
    (when (file-newer-than-file-p src byte)
      (byte-compile-file src))
    (message "Loading %s.elc" byte)
    (load-file byte)))
```

It loads configuration files from `~/.emacs.d` which start with a number. If the source file (extension `.el`) is newer than the byte-compiled version (extension `.elc`) then it byte-compiles the source. Afterwards it loads the byte compiled file.

Comment: Note that https://github.com/tarsius/auto-compile is an (excellent) generalisation of this "compile/load the latest version" approach, which takes care of *all* libraries loaded by Emacs, and not only your custom ones. Highly recommended.

Comment: Thanks everyone. So combining answers from Tobias, phils and lunaryorn would be the answer. Thus I'll tick this one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my `~/.emacs`:

```
;; base dirs
(defvar dropbox.d "~/Dropbox/")
(defvar emacs.d (concat dropbox.d "source/site-lisp/"))
;; load path
(add-to-list 'load-path emacs.d)
(defun add-subdirs-to-load-path (dir)
    (let ((default-directory dir))
      (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path)))
(add-subdirs-to-load-path emacs.d)
(load "init")
```

All my other scripts are loaded by `~/Dropbox/source/site-lisp/init.el`
and are themselves located in `~/Dropbox/source/site-lisp`.
That's how I have the same config on multiple machines.
And here's how `.../site-lisp/hooks.el` is loaded from `init.el`:

```
(load "hooks")
```

My `init.el` is about 100 lines, `.emacs` about 20 lines.
The rest 8000 lines of scripts are sliced into around 20 files.

Comment: So your around 20 files are taken care of by the `add-subdirs-to-load-path`, or there is more magics behind?

Comment: Yes, it takes care of the directory structure. I can create
a new directory in the base and any files there will also be seen.

Answer (score 1):

`~/.emacs.d/` does **not** work like `/etc/profile.d/` or `/etc/modules-load.d/` or similar directories, i.e. Emacs does **not** automatically load any Emacs Lisp file in this directory.

In fact, Emacs explicitly advises **against** placing Emacs Lisp libraries in `~/.emacs.d/`.  The byte compiler emits a warning if you add `~/.emacs.d/` to the `load-path`.

Instead, create a new sub-directory, e.g. `~/.emacs.d/lisp`.  Add this directory to your `load-path` *explicitly*, with the following code in `init.el`:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path (locate-user-emacs-file "lisp"))
```

Then, place your Emacs Lisp files in this directory, e.g. `~/.emacs.d/lisp/foo.el`, and load them in your `init.el`:

```
(load "foo" nil 'no-message)
```

The best approach to avoid the dreaded .emacs bankruptcy is to actually *avoid* large customizations!  Most notably, try to avoid any custom functions and commands.

Instead, try to a find an ELPA package that comes closest to what you want, and either try to get used to it, or customize it to your needs.  If you don't find any, first try to write your own and distribute it on Github, Marmalade or MELPA.

Don't be afraid of maintaining a package in the public.  You'll have to maintain your customization anyway, whether in your `init.el` or not, so you can just as well let other Emacs users help you with this job.

Adding code to your `init.el` should be your **very last resort**!

Comment: "try to avoid any custom functions and commands", that's almost inevitable with Emacs, 'cause Emacs people seems to be living in an entirely different world. For example, for all editors that I use, pressing the `Delete` key will delete the text selection, but Emacs people insists to be different and remove that existing feature (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816385/emacs-use-delete-key-to-delete-selection/20816584#20816584).

Comment: @xpt It is evitable.  Either adapt to the changes in Emacs (which seldom happen without reason), or try to find (or maintain yourself) a package which re-introduces the desired functionality.